# Sending Json objet using httpclient to drupal Android

Tags: android

I am trying to send data from json to equivalent php format below output using json.put();

```
Array
    (
        [node] => Array
            (
                [name] => admin
                [type] => mobile_content
                [language] => und
                [title] => re resss re@fffd.com
                [field_one] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => re
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_prenom] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => resss
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_addr] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => re@fffd.com
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_email] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 01/01/1913
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_collectif] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_bach] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 0
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_mc_rec] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_photo] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [fid] => 1778
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

my problem is i cannot get the format properly.

```
i created my json object



        try {


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
```

then put the node using

```
json.put("node[type]","type");
```

then finally send the json output to

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler<String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(path);

    String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
            ("uname" + ":" + "pword").getBytes(),
            Base64.NO_WRAP);

    postMethod.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);
    postMethod.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");       
    postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(params.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));

    String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);

    if (response.equals("[]")) //empty
        return null;
    else
    {
        System.out.println("response :" + response);
        JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(response);

        return jObject;
    }
```

My error log shows

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Acceptable: Node type is required
```

but on the serverside i no log is shown. Meaning the json object is not being sent. This is weird. Note that i am sending to drupal. help please. Is this the right way to send text format json to server.

Comment: Give some more exception log lines. It's seems on Android side exception, but not on server, but need more log lines of exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i do

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(postObject
                                .toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
                        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                                "application/json"));
                        request.setEntity(se);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

And then read response entity. But i wrote own server side php API.

Also checkout similar question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031090/how-to-prevent-http-406-status-code-error-from-server

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days ago. When creating a node a type and title are required fields for the node to be created. The error that you have says that "type" was not provided. I would print out the JSON that you are attempting to post and make sure that the type field looks like

```
{"type":"mobile_content"}
```

and that there are no misspellings or capital letters, because it is case sensitive. Do the same for title as well.